# Is insoluble $p$-adic analytic just-infinite pro-$p$ group torsion-free?

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-groups

Recall that an infinite pro-$p$ group $G$ is called *just-infinite* if all non-trivial closed normal subgroup of $G$ have finite index.

**Question:** Let $G$ be an insoluble $p$-adic analytic just-infinite pro-$p$ group. Is it true that $G$ is torsion-free?

If $\text{dim}~G<p-1$, then it is true, cf. Theorem 1.3 in [Klopsch, Benjamin. "On the Lie theory of p-adic analytic groups." Mathematische Zeitschrift 249 (2005): 713-730.] Any references or counterexample will be appreciated.

**Added.** Let $p$ be an odd prime. The following are equivalent:

- (1) Any insoluble $p$-adic analytic just-infinite pro-$p$ group is torsion-free.
- (2) Any Sylow-pro-$p$ subgroup of ${\rm SL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ is torsion-free for any $n\geq 2$.

*Sketch of proof:*

- $(1)\implies (2)$: Note that any Sylow-pro-$p$ subgroup of ${\rm SL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ is an insoluble $p$-adic analytic just-infinite pro-$p$ group;
- $(2)\implies (1)$: Let $G$ be any insoluble $p$-adic analytic just-infinite pro-$p$ group. Then $G$ is isomorphic to a closed subgroup of ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ for some positive integer $n$. Since the abelianization of $G$ is a finite $p$-group, $G$ is isomorphic to a closed subgroup of ${\rm SL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_p)$. Thus, $G$ must be torsion-free.

Comment: Do you know the answer in the various cases where $G$ is chosen as an open subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ for $n\ge 2$?

Comment: When $n\geq 2$ and $p>n+1$, then any open pro-$p$ subgroup of ${\rm SL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ is torsion-free.

Comment: Have you thought about the case $p=n$?

Comment: @SimonWadsley I guess it fails for the case $p=n$. But I don't know how to construct a concrete torsion element at the moment.

Comment: Think about permutation matrices.

Comment: @SimonWadsley Thanks. Take $p=n=3$. The matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ belongs to $ {\rm SL}_{3}(\mathbf{Z}_{3}) $ of order $p=3$. This gives a counter example.

Comment: Your example generalises for any p=n.